# When exception raised rollingback the insert

Tags: postgresql

I am calling the function 
SELECT sbc_schemaA.func1(customernum =>  '5566789',custlocID =>  25)

Whenever there is an exception raised in sbc_schemaD.func5 the insert statemet of sbc_schemaC.func4 is rolledback.

Even exception is raised it should not rollback the into custgartbl.

Please help me.

The code of the function    sbc_schemaA.func1 as below.
It is calling another function "sbc_schemaB.func2" inside it.

```
create or replace function sbc_schemaA.func1(
        customernum in VARCHAR default null,
        custlocID in NUMERIC default null
    ) RETURNS void AS
    $$
    declare
        ajsid numeric;
begin
select * from sbc_schemaB.func2(customernum, custlocID) into strict ajsid;
exception
when raise_exception then
RAISE info '%','ErrMsg: ' || substr(sqlerrm,1,instr(sqlerrm,e'\n',1,1)) ;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

The code of the function    sbc_schemaB.func2 as below.
It is calling another function "sbc_schemaC.func3" inside it.

```
 create or replace  function sbc_schemaB.func2(                     
                                 customernumber IN VARCHAR,
                                 custlocID IN NUMERIC,
                                 brsid out NUMERIC) AS
                                 $$
declare
v_ermsg text;
v_cnx text;
begin
select * from sbc_schemaC.func3(customernumber => customernumber,custlocID => custlocID) into strict brsid; 
    exception
        when raise_exception then
                            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_ermsg = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
                            v_cnx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
                            v_ermsg := set_context(v_ermsg::text, v_cnx::Text);
                            raise exception e'%', v_ermsg;     
end $$ language plpgsql;

The code of the function    sbc_schemaC.func3 as below.
It is calling another function "sbc_schemaC.func4" and "sbc_schemaD.func5" inside it.

create or replace  function sbc_schemaC.func3(customernumber     IN VARCHAR,
                            custlocID        IN NUMERIC,
                            ajsid         out NUMERIC,
                            brsid    out NUMERIC) AS
          $$
    declare
v_ajsid numeric;    
btpID numeric:=0;
        select * from sbc_schemaC.func4(p_customernum        => customernumber,
                         p_custlocID     => custlocID
                        ) into v_ajsid;

        ajsid := v_ajsid;

 if v_ajsid = 0 then
begin
select * from  sbc_schemaD.func5(customernumber,btpID);
exception
 when raise_exception then 
                    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_ermsg = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
                            v_cnx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
                            v_ermsg := set_context(v_ermsg::text, v_cnx::Text);
                            raise exception e'%', v_ermsg;

end;
end if;
end $$ language plpgsql;    

The code of the function    sbc_schemaC.func4 as below.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sbc_schemaC.func4(
p_customernum VARCHAR,  
p_custlocID numeric, 
p_ajsid OUT numeric
) AS
          $$
    declare
        v_cnx text;
        v_ermsg text;
                begin
insert into custgartbl(account_num,custlocID) values(p_customernum,p_custlocID);
exception
    when raise_exception then
             GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_ermsg = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
            v_cnx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
            v_ermsg := set_context(v_ermsg::text, v_cnx::Text);
            raise exception e'%', v_ermsg;
    end $$ language plpgsql;    

The code of the function    sbc_schemaD.func5 as below.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sbc_schemaD.func5 (customernumber text, btpID numeric) AS $body$
DECLARE
        errmsg text;
        v_ermsg text;
        v_cnx text;     
BEGIN
if btpID = 0 then
errmsg := cermssg('error')
                 raise exception e'%',errmsg;
            end if;
   exception
        when raise_exception then       
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS 
        v_ermsg = MESSAGE_TEXT,  
        v_cnx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
           v_ermsg := v_ermsg||E'\n'||v_cnx;
        raise exception e'%', v_ermsg;          
    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you catching and re-raising the exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

The code you post for `func3` is buggy; it is missing the initial `BEGIN`.

Anyway, when simplified, your code looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM func4(...) INTO ...;

IF v_ajsid = 0 THEN
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM func5(...);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN raise_exception THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION ...;
   END;
END IF;
```

Since you raise an exception in the exception handler, the whole (sub?)transaction in which `func3` is executed gets rolled back, so the effects of the call to `func4` are undone.

You have to something other than raising an exception in the exception handler if you want to preserve the effects of the call to `func4`.

Comment: Don't put a `RAISE` in the exception handler. I cannot write your code for you.

Comment: Hi,

The exception should be raised because we have to show the exception in the csv file.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended to answer questions, not to tutor beginning programmers.